# Python + Sqlite: Unable to determine cause of incorrect number of bindings supplied error

Tags: python, sqlite

I'll get right into it - I first created a local db for myself:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("tofire.db") #

cursor = conn.cursor()

# create a table

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE incidents
                  (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, prime_street text, cross_street text, dispatch_time text, 
                   incident_number text, incident_type text, alarm_level text, area text, dispatched_units text, date_added text)
               """)
```

This went without a hitch - the next part is my function, and it uses beautiful soup to scrape a table into a list of lists. I am then attempting to write the information in each sublist to the sqlite database.

```
# Toronto Fire Calls

import urllib2
import sqlite3
import time
import csv
import threading
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Beautiful Soup imports the URL as html
def getincidents ():

    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.toronto.ca/fire/cadinfo/livecad.htm')

    html = response.read()

    # We give the html its own variable.

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    # Find the table we want on the Toronto Fire Page

    table = soup.find("table", class_="info")

    # Find all the <td> tags in the table and assign them to variable.

    cols = table.find_all('td')

    # Find the length of rows, which is the number of <font> tags, and assign it to a variable num_cols.

    num_cols = len(cols)

    # Create an empty list to hold each of the <font> tags as an element

    colslist = []
    totalcols = 0
    # For each <font> in cols, append it to colslist as an element.

    for col in cols:
        colslist.append(col.string)
        totalcols = len(colslist)

    # Now colslist has every td as an element from [0] to totalcols = len(colslist)

    # The First 8 <font> entries are always the table headers i.e. Prime Street, Cross Street, etc.

    headers = colslist[0:8]

    # Prime Street
    # Cross Street
    # Dispatch Time
    # Incident Number
    # Incident Type
    # Alarm Level
    # Area
    # Dispatched Units

    # Get the indexes from 0 to the length of the original list, in steps of list_size, then create a sublist for each.
    # lists = [original_list[i:i+list_size] for i in xrange(0, len(original_list), list_size)]
    list_size = 8
    i = 0
    incidents = [colslist[i:i+list_size] for i in xrange(0, len(colslist), list_size)]

    # Works!

    num_inci = len(incidents) # Get the number of incidents
    added = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    update = 'DB Updated @ ' + added

    # SQL TIME, Connect to our db.
    conn = sqlite3.connect("tofire.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    lid = cursor.lastrowid

    # Now we put each incident into our database.

    for incident in incidents[1:num_inci]:
        incident.append(added)
        to_db = [(i[0:10]) for i in incident]
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO incidents (prime_street, cross_street, dispatch_time, incident_number, incident_type, alarm_level, area, dispatched_units, date_added) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", to_db)
    conn.commit()
    print update
    print "The last Id of the inserted row is %d" % lid
    threading.Timer(300, getincidents).start()

getincidents()
```

I always end up with error message "Incorrect Number of Bindings Supplied" - and it claims that I'm trying to use 9 in my statement when 10 are supplied. I've tried to narrow down the cause of this, but have had no success.

Comment: Your statement has 9 question marks, not 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ned Batchelder recently put it, "First Rule of Debugging: When in Doubt, Print More Out." After you append `added` to `incident`, `incident` itself has 9 items in it:

```
print(incident)
# [u'NORFINCH DR, NY', u'FINCH AVE W / HEPC', u'2012-12-09 17:32:57', u'F12118758', u'Medical - Other', u'0', u'142', u'\r\nP142, \r\n\r\n', '2012-12-09 17:46']
```

So it looks like all you really need to do is use `incident` as the second argument to `cursor.execute`. Or, if you want to get rid of some of that whitespace around items like `u'\r\nP142, \r\n\r\n'`,
you could use

```
    to_db = [i.strip() for i in incident]
```

---

```
for incident in incidents[1:num_inci]:
    incident.append(added)
    to_db = [i.strip() for i in incident]
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    cursor.execute(
        """INSERT INTO incidents
           (prime_street, cross_street, dispatch_time, incident_number,
            incident_type, alarm_level, area, dispatched_units, date_added)
           VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""", to_db)
    lid = cursor.lastrowid
```

Comment: unutbu - Thanks millions for that - I have a feeling that it is going to work with one more little tweak; It's throwing a `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level` - can your experienced eyes see where I might have screwed up?

Comment: Well, it is an indentation error, which means I'd have to look at your actual code to find it. Be careful about tabs looking like spaces -- you should stick to all tabs or all spaces. Don't mix them. You might try running your script with `python -t script.py` to have Python tell you if mixing tabs and spaces is the source of the problem. On Unix, you can also do `cat -A script.py` to see where the tabs and spaces are.

Comment: That was what did it. Thanks again for the help. The detail level of your suggestions was inspiring!

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying 10 elements to an insert statement that you have defined to only take 9 elements

either

```
to_db = [(i[0:9]) for i in incident]  #or
to_db = [(i[1:10]) for i in incident]
```

will give you nine elements... which matches the number of ? marks in your insert statement (and the number of fields you are populating) ...

which im assuming is what you want

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - more strangeness;
When I use i[0:9] it errors as "statement uses 9, when 8 are supplied", and when I use [1:10], it errors as "statement uses 9, and there are 1 supplied".

Comment: try `print map(len,to_db)` before you do your execute many .. and maybe a `print to_db`